# 301 redirect with ? (question mark) not working in htacces

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect, redirect, redirecttoaction

This is probably an easy question, but we can not find why the 301 is not working. When we have a url with a question mark the 301 redirect in our `.htacces` is not working. For example:

```
/order/order.html?AddID=1078&Rand=666171759380936096
```

so:
`Redirect 301 /order/order.html?AddID=1078&Rand=666171759380936096` http://www.domain.nl

In our webmaster tools we have 8000 url's with the same structure `/order/order.html?AddID=....` that say **404** not found. We want to **301** redirect them to the homepage, but we get a **404** not found page instead. when we use the same redirect with only `/order/order.html` he is redirected correct.

Comment: what is your .httaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `Redirect` statement, use mod_rewrite and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^AddID=1078&Rand=666171759380936096$
RewriteRule ^order/order.html$ http://www.domain.nl/? [L,R=301]
```

But since you have like 8000 URLs that start with the query string `?AddID=`, then you can just match against that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^AddID=[0-9]
RewriteRule ^order/order.html$ http://www.domain.nl/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Dear Jon Lin, Thanks for your reply. I have tested the query string but am still getting a 404 page not found. Can it be that it has something to do with: AddID=[0-9] this are number and I see that there are also figures 1078&Rand=66? Do you have an other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: @Coen The `[0-9]` is just the first character. Dunno what's wrong, it works fine for me in a blank htaccess file.

Comment: above I have placed an second answer above to show what the results are when I implement your suggestion

Comment: @Coen I left out a `?` at the end of the target, but not sure if that's the problem you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried it again and now I placed it right in the top of the htacces, see printscreen. In this case it is about the url (normally I do not place my own url) www.tablet.nl and if you place one of our 404 pages /order/order.html?AddID=1037&Rand=539054443213186002 behind the url, /order/order.html is deleted and only ?AddID=1037&Rand=539054443213186002 is shown behind the main url with a 404 page not found.

Any idea and I let the htacces as shown in the attachement so you can test the url.

Let me know

[image]