# htaccess redirect for part of url with characters (? and =)

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a Joomla website and I have recently installed a calendar component. I need to be able to redirect part of a url so that the calendar works properly (it's complicated to explain why).

The URL structure is: http://domain.com/calendar?ids=8#year=2015&month=2&day=25&view=list

I need the "?ids=8" removed from after calendar, so I tried a couple of different redirect scripts I'd seen but it seems to trip on the ? and the = signs..

Here's what I had tried but it didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^/?calendar?ids=8(.*)$ /calendar$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any advice?

Kind regards
Liam

Comment: RewriteRule matches only on the path component of the URL; if want to match on the query string, you need to precede your your rule with a RewriteCond to do that.

Comment: I don't suppose you could correct mine could you please CBroe? I've found RewriteCond examples online but I don't fully understand it and I can't find any examples where there's part of the url before and after the part that is being found.

Comment: Ahhh found a version that I managed to adapt to work. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493473/301-redirect-with-question-mark-not-working-in-htacces